# find sequences which are convergent with respect to the $d_{l^\infty}$ metric but not with respect to the $d_{l^1}$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

(Exercise 1.1.15 in Real Analysis 2 by Tao) Let 
$$X : = \{(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty : \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| < \infty\}$$ 
be the space of absolutely convergent sequences. Define the $l^1$ and $l^\infty$ metrics on this space by

$$d_{l^1} ((a_n)_{n=0}^\infty, (b_n)_{n=0}^\infty) : = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n - b_n|;$$ 
$$d_{l^\infty} ((a_n)_{n=0}^\infty, (b_n)_{n=0}^\infty) : = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n - b_n|.$$

Show that there exist sequences $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}, ...$ of elements of $X$ (i.e. sequence of sequences) which are convergent with respect to the $d_{l^\infty}$ metric but not with respect to the $d_{l^1}$ metric. Conversely, show that any sequence which converges in the $d_{l^1}$ metric automatically converges in the $d_{l^\infty}$ metric.

Let $x^{(k)}$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}d_{l^1} ( (x^{(k)}_n)_{n=1}^\infty, x)  =0$. Then, $|x_i^{(k)} - x_i| < \epsilon$ for all $i$. Thus, $x^{(k)}$ converges to $x$ in $d_{l^\infty}$ as well. This prove the second part of the question. I have difficulty in proving the first part of the question. Can you give some help?

Comment: Recall that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ to converge.

Comment: Hint: look for an example where $x^{(j)}$ only has $j$ nonzero elements at the front, and where the $\{ x^{(j)} \}$ tend to the zero sequence in the $d_{\ell^\infty}$ metric.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. A sequence $(1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ come up to my mind because this converges to $0$, but the series diverges. However, $d_{l^\infty} ( (1/n)_{n=1}^\infty, 0 ) \not= 0$. Can you give some more hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, we can take $$x^{(n)}=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,\dots)$$where the $n+1,n+2,...$-th entries of $x^{(n)}$ are all $0$. Then it needs to be checked that $x^{(n)}$ cannot converge in $d_{l_1}$ norm.

Edit.

Suppose that $x^{(n)}$ converges to some $x$ in $d_{l^1}$, then it can be checked that $x=(0,0,\dots)$ as follows:

Let $x(k)=$ the $k$-th coordinate of $x$. Then $$|x(k)-x^n(k)|\le d_{l^1}(x,x^{(n)})$$Taking $n\to\infty$ to see $x(k)=0$, hence $x=(0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am not sure how to prove the sequence does not converge w.r.t. $d_{l^1}$ . $d_{l^1}(x^{(n)}, 0) = 1$, so it does not converges to $0$, but this does not mean that $x^{(n)}$ does not converge w.r.t. $d_{l^1}$. Could you provide some more explanation?

Comment: @shk910: it can be checked that if $x^{(n)}$ converges in $d_{l^1}$, then the limit must be $0$, see the edit for details

Comment: OK. Then should I argue that if $x^{(n)}$ converges w.r.t $d_{l^1}$, the limit must be $0$, but since $d_{l^1}(x^{(n)}, 0) =1$,  $x^{(n)}$ does not converges w.r.t $d_{l^1}$?

Comment: @shk910 exactly