# Show that the set $\{e^{(n)} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed and bounded subset of $X$, but is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d_{l^1})$ be the metric space from Exercise [1.1.15](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553285/find-sequences-which-are-convergent-with-respect-to-the-d-l-infty-metric-bu). For each natural number $n$, let $e^{(n)} = (e^{(n)}_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ be the sequence in $X$ such that $e^{(n)}_j : = 1$ when $n=j$ and $e^{(n)}_j:=0$ when $n \not= j$. Show that the set $\{e^{(n)} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a closed and bounded subset of $X$, but is not compact.

The set is bounded since $d_{l^1}(e^{(j)}, e^{(k)}) \le 2$ for all $j,k \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e., there exists a ball which contain the set).

Consider the sequence $(e^{(n)})_{n=0}^\infty$. This sequence is not Cauchy because $d_{l^1}(e^{(j)},e^{(k)}) = 2$ for every $j \not= k$. Also, there exists no subsequence which is convergent in this set. Thus, it is not compact.

How can I show closedness? Is my proof correct?

Comment: Show that the set contains all its limit points?  Come to think of it, does it have any?

Comment: So, it looks like it's an infinite discrete space.  So of course not compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done so far is correct. To show that the set is closed suppose $x$ belong to its closure. Then $(e^{(n_k)})$ converges to $x$ for some $(n_k)$. If $n_k$'s are distinct then $2=d(e^{(n_k)}, e^{(n_j)})$ must tend to $0$ as $j,k \to \infty$ which is a contradiction. Thus there is an eventually constant sequence converging to $x$ and Hence $x$ belongs to the set.

Answer (score 0):

The set doesn't have any limit points.  Thus it's closed.

The rest looks fine.